# testing node.js with expresso - redis session store

Tags: tdd, node.js, redis

I am trying to learn TDD with node.js. I've hit this issue with expresso where the `expresso` command just hangs, I think because of the redis-server. Killing the process with `ctrl+C` finally gives the output I'm looking for (100% 3 tests passed).

What's causing the `expresso` command to hang, and what can I do about it?

My app looks like this:

```
// Module dependencies.

var auth = require('connect-auth'),
    RedisStore = require('connect-redis');


var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ store: new RedisStore, secret: "secret goes here" }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

// Routes

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Orchestrate'
  });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('user/login', {
    title: 'Login'
  });
});

app.get('/register', function(req, res){
  res.render('user/login', {
    title: 'Register'
  });
});

// Only listen on $ node app.js

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port);
}
```

And my tests:

```
// Run $ expresso

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app'),
    assert = require('assert');


module.exports = {
  'GET /': function(){
    assert.response(app,
      { url: '/' },
      { status: 200, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' }},
      function(res){
        assert.includes(res.body, '<title>Orchestrate</title>');
      });
  },
  'GET /login': function(){
    assert.response(app,
      { url: '/login' },
      { status: 200, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' }},
      function(res){
        assert.includes(res.body, '<title>Login</title>');
      });
  },
  'GET /register': function(){
    assert.response(app,
      { url: '/register' },
      { status: 200, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' }},
      function(res){
        assert.includes(res.body, '<title>Register</title>');
      });
  }
```

};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing your tests like this and the test runner should terminate itself when all the tests have finished:

```
  'GET /': function(done){
    assert.response(app,
      { url: '/' },
      { status: 200, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' }},
      function(res){
        assert.includes(res.body, '<title>Orchestrate</title>');

        done();
      });
```

Comment: Where does the `done()` function come from and what are it's effects ?

Comment: Oh, figured it out, it's the param.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that Mongoose doesn't close the connections itself nicely, which causes issues when using expresso.

You need to add a "mongoose.disconnect()", e.g. I always add a 'tear down' step at the end:

```
    tearDown: function(done){
       mongoose.disconnect();
       done();
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is no teardown/setup functionality in Expresso (if you create a tearDown function in your test, it will be run along with the other tests, in any order it will appear). Anyway I voted this answer up because, also for Redis, you need to end() the client or the test suite will not exit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the asserts are printed after asynchronous calls. Your tests are not hanged because of connect-redis, they just don't know when all your tests passed.

Comment: I though it was connect-redis, because that's what I changed before expresso started hanging.
Is it something I should worry about, or just continue killing it with ctrl+c (any solution?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem with

```
mongoose.connect();
```

expresso tests terminate as expected as long as i don't connect to the db, otherwise i need to kill the process to see the results.

Comment: I have the same issue- upon running a test that involves a db, the test does not terminate and hangs. Any change?

Answer (score 0):

For people hitting this problem in the future, looks like the successor to Expresso called [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) solves this problem.  It supports true initialization and tear down functions as well as a Done() callback to fix the async completion issue.